# Add account field to asp.net forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, webforms, identity, simplemembership

What's the best way to implement an additional user identifier in an ASP.NET forms web application?

At the database level a user is identified by a user and account number.

```
userA AccountA passwordA
userA AccountB passwordB
userA AccountC passwordC
```

I'm looking to leverage (loggin, create user, etc) as much of the asp.net authentication framework as possible and I'm open to any version (ASP.NET `Membership`, `SimpleMembership`, `MemberShipReboot`, ASP.NET `Identity`). I've been strongly discouraged to use a custom membership provider.

Comment: _" I've been strongly discouraged to use a custom membership provider."_ Why? You can always create a custom provider by inheriting from an existing. Then you don't need to create it from scratch and you can extend/change it as needed.

Comment: I agree with the "why". I think my clients believe the implementation process will be faster and more secure if we use the defaults and mix their existing authorization process into it. But I haven't seen an easy way to add/update/delete user in a standard way, with the additional "account" field. Maybe, concatenate the user name, like userA:AccountA?